# Action cable in rails application with subdomain - apartment gem isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, apartment-gem

`Rails 5`,  `apartment gem`

action cable `connection.rb`

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user, :tenant

    def connect
      self.tenant = request.subdomain
      Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)

      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.try(:email) || 'Unauthenticated User'
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        # May have public users accessing the channels
        # reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

environments/production.rb

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ /https:\/\/(.*).mydomain.com/ ]
```

Tried above code reference taken from these links: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982812/rails-actioncable-request-origins-subdomain) and [Link 2](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/391) but not working.

In production: `request.subdomain` is `nil`(tried with hot coding some tenant values, but not working)

In development: `request.subdomain` gives the tenant name, but actual request isn't working.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue:

`request.subdomain` isn't working and returns "". Alternatively I passed the tenant value through query string

```
const getWebSocketURL = () => {
    var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://';
    var host = window.location.host;
    var path = '/cable';
    var url = protocol + host + path;
    return `${url}?tenant=mytenant`;
};
```

and

```
const wsUrl = getWebSocketURL();
const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(wsUrl);
```

connection.rb:

```
self.tenant = request.params[:tenant]
```

Also inside yours channels in every method you first line should be

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!(tenant)
```

here you can get the tenant values from room

see these links too:
[how-to-set-tenant-in-actioncable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468932/how-to-set-tenant-in-actioncable-with-milia-for-multi-tenancy/49519110#49519110)
[rails-actioncable-request-origins-subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982812/rails-actioncable-request-origins-subdomain/41985863#41985863)